# Mobile Version of Site Always Opens Up Much Bigger Than Screen

Tags: css, mobile, meta-tags

Im trying to open up my latest site design on my phone and have it match the screen when i go to the url.  However, it always open up much bigger and I have to double tap the screen to resize it to the correct size.

I've tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But nothing is working. Please view source on my site and html at:

http://directsellers.org/NeverTakeNo4Answer/LetsGo.html

and tell me what I need to fix.  Thanks.

Comment: Check your code back as i can't see any code/lines for responsive part.

Comment: There are no css file in your page. Please check.

Comment: the css is in the head section of the html, i dont have any attached pages

Answer (score 1):

I faced the problem like you did.
So you have to set your html and body width, not in pecentage or pixels, but in vw (viewport width). For example:

```
body, html {
 width: 100vw;
 min-width: 100vw;
 max-width: 100vw;

 overflow-x: hidden
 overflow-y: auto
}
```

I did this way, and it works.

Comment: thanx for trying to help but you just can't manage your whole site's reponsiveness with few lines. You MUST have to code it according to your requirements so please don't post such low answers. Thanx

Comment: @Leothelion i know, he just asked, that when he is opening a website it seems big, but if you change your max width to your viewport width, that might fix the problem. I know that responsive design needs to recode almost everything, but i just answered a question according to the problem he has

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the CSS for the Responsive Design. You need to target the device width using media queries and write CSS for mobile and tablets.

Please follow the link below to get an idea about it.
http://www.zell-weekeat.com/how-to-write-mobile-first-css

Comment: the media query is already in the file and the site is already mobilized with unique css for mobile.

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {

that line is already there.  Everything works except for the site opening much bigger then needing double tapping to bring in to correct size

Answer (score 0):

You give fixed Width. just give `width:100%`. to all div and content. it will automatically responsive